# Asignar vista a Usuario SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Hola amigos necesito que me ayuden con una problema que tengo.

Tengo 2 base de datos (b1,b2) donde desde la b2 creé una vista (ventas) que saca de la b1, el cuál funciona correctamente; necesito crear un usuario que pueda acceder a esa vista y nada más.

La razón de cual creé la vista en b2 es que no puedo crear nada en la b1, sino sólo consultar.

Los problemas que me he encontrado son:

- Asigne los permisos a un 'usuario1' desde b2 pero luego de loguearme no tiene permisos para ver la vista (Ventas) a razón que el 'usuario1' no tiene permisos para la b1.
- Seguí un [tuto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085700/restrict-sql-server-login-access-to-only-one-database) el cuál puedo acceder a la vista, pero también accede a la b1 y b2 el cuál no quiero que el 'usuario1' acceda a esa información, sino solo a la vista (Ventas)

Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1)

Espero que me puedan ayudar, les agradezco muchas gracias

ACTUALIZACION:

Necesito que el 'usuario1' acceda a la vista (Ventas)y solo a eso. 
- Con el tuto mencionado anteriormente:
En la primera conexión tengo privilegios y accedo a las base de datos b1 y b2, desde b2 creé el 'usuario1'; cuando realizo la segunda conexión con el 'usuario1' accedo a la vista (ventas) pero también tengo acceso a las tablas de b1 y b2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuando decis que no queres que acceda a b1, que queres decir? a b1 tiene que acceder con permisos de select por lo menos a esa tabla. Puede que no tenga permisos para hacer select a otras tablas, pero va a tener que acceder a b1 si o si..

Comment: Hola @gbianchi que no acceda a las tablas de b1, desde b2 creo la vista que saca datos de b1, pero que acceda sólo a esa vista o mejor dicho solo vea ese recurso. Actualizaré la publicación con una imagen muchas gracias x tu tiempo

Comment: me da la impresión de que tendrias que crear un rol para ese usuario, que solo tenga select en la vista y luego agregar el usuario a ese rol (sacandolo del public rol group) asi de memoria no te sabria decir como, tal vez un ms sql expert pueda dar los pasos correctos

Comment: Cómo creaste la vista? En dónde necesitas crear el usuario con acceso restringido sólo a la vista?

Comment: hola @Alfabravo la vista la cree en la b2 usando datos (tablas) de la b1 el usuario debe estar creado en la b2; como dije no puedo crear nada en otras base de datos

Answer (score 1):

creo que algo así debería de funcionar...

Créate un **Rol** que tenga permisos de lectura a las tablas de *b1*. Mete tu usuario de *b2* en el rol y prueba a construir de nuevo la vista.

*Actualiza los objetos que manipules entre acción y acción

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Carlos voy a intentar tu sugerencia soy novato en sql server talves me podrias ayudar con algun tuto muchas gracias

Comment: Tienes una amplia ayuda en el apartado Docs de Microsoft. Te paso 3 enlaces para crear el usuario de base de datos, las credencias y los roles y cómo gestionar sus permisos:[enlace]https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user  [enlace]https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-server-role    [enlace]https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles